# FME - Convert DWG to JPG

Tags: convert, fme-form, translation

I am a beginner in Safe FME and i need to know how to Convert DWG files to JPG Files. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

**Rasterizer Transformer**

tip: Force 2D first

http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Converting-Vector-data-to-Raster#heading_toc_j_3

Answer (score 1):

Safe FME supports reading and writing in JPEG formats - [Details](http://www.safe.com/fme/format-search/jpeg-joint-photographic-experts-group/index.php). For converting DWG to JPG you will have to use a suitable [transformer](http://www.safe.com/fme/key-capabilities/data-transformation/).

Comment: I Tried to use ImageRasterizer, but it does not display correctly.

Comment: Have you taken care of this caveat: *The fme_color attribute of the input vector features is used to generate pixel values. Features without an fme_color attribute will be discarded.*

Comment: The procedure to use ImageRasterizer is something like [this](http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2009/08/create-geotiff-image-from-shape-file.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert dwg to jpg online then here is the [dwg to jpg converter](https://www.watermark-images.com/dwg-to-jpg-conversion.aspx) tool

Answer (score -1):

I used VeryUtils DWG to Image Converter to convert my 200+ DWG files to JPG files from command line, I wrote a .bat file to do this work, it worked fine for me.

Comment: Obviously this part "I wrote a .bat file" is the important part of the answer. Please edit your answer so it provides the relevant code.