# Automate SHP to JPG creation

Tags: shapefile, convert, jpg

Does anyone know of a way to batch convert shapefiles to jpegs or another common image format?

edit: I should have clarified that I would like to apply a styling to each shapefile, and then export the shapefile with that styling to an image.

For example, I have census tracts in a county, and I want an image of each individual tract highlighted while the other tracts are all the same color.

Comment: Do you have any particular software in mind?  An application that you use regularly?  Or do you just any way possible?

Comment: I use Arc and Q pretty regularly and am getting more familiar with arcpy, but am really just looking for any way to do this, even another third party software package

Comment: So for clarification, you are basically just looking to generate thumbnails (or larger) of the shapefile, no styling, no colors, no labels, etc right?

Comment: I started thinking about this last night, and I see that my original question might be misleading.  I would like to apply a styling and then export the map over 100+ times for each indiviual shapefile with the applied styling.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are many free tools like:

- [gdal rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html)
- [Map Tyler](http://www.maptiler.org/)
- it is easy to do with Python and modules like [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) and a simple for loop:
  [image]

But in Python, the reference is [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) and [Getting Started In Python](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/GettingStartedInPython)

- You create a map (width and height in pixels, background color, etc)
- You create Styles which determines how the data is rendered
- You add a datasource (shapefile, etc.) and create a layer from it.
- You render the map
- the same map and styles parameters can be applied to multiple files (via an XML file)

see the examples in [Mapniks Maps](http://mapnik.org/maps/)

Simple Rendered images from TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp

[image]

selection of a country (Angola) in the shapefile:

[image]

Another example from [Mapniks Maps](http://mapnik.org/maps/)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could add all of the layers to a mxd, then loop through them and run

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(map_document, out_jpeg, {data_frame}, {df_export_width}, {df_export_height}, {resolution}, {world_file}, {color_mode}, {jpeg_quality}, {progressive})
```

for each layer in the map.

Comment: Just to add to this solution, you could use arcpy.da.walk to generate an initial list of input data: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000023000000

Answer (score 3):

This [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/10188/7424) has answers that use [FME](http://www.safe.com/) to convert DWG to JPG.  The process will be similar for converting shapefiles.

[This example](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Converting-Vector-data-to-Raster#heading_toc_j_3) has example workspaces you can download.

FME is well suited to handling batch processes.  For example, you can point the reader to a folder and it will include all shapefiles in the folder.

I created a simple workflow which reads all the shapefiles in a folder and writes them out to separate JPGs.

[image: workflow]

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I did this yesterday with counties in Montana!  Is it too late to answer?  Assuming you've already used Split to make a shapefile for each census tract, I found that it was easy (lazy) to handle them in a Group Layer.  Assuming that's the only Group Layer in your document, don't be shy about opening up the ArcPy window and entering:

```
# Setup, defining a variable for the map document, the data frame,
# and a list of layers:
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)

# To copy symbology to all subLayers in the group layer,
# using a template, any normal polygon shapefile will do:
# (datum conflict warnings are irrelevant)
for layer in layers:
  if layer.isGroupLayer:
    for subLayer in layer:
      arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(subLayer, "templatelayer")

# Export one map with each county/tract highlighted, toggling visibility
# of each sublayer before and after:
for layer in layers:
  if layer.isGroupLayer:
    for subLayer in layer:
      print "Exporting " + str(subLayer.name)
      subLayer.visible = True
      slfile = "C:\\YourPathHere\\Subdir\\Etc\\" + str(subLayer.name) +
".png"
      arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, slfile, df, df_export_width=640,
df_export_height=480, transparent_color="255, 255, 255")
      subLayer.visible = False
```

Export to jpg is similar, but jpgs are kinda yucky.  This was my first ArcPy experience, so I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this.

Comment: You did do the exact same thing eh?  Glad you figured it out, thanks for the response

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python script I use. It can modified to change the colour of the polygons, &c:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import random
import shapefile
import sys

def get_cmap(n, name='hsv'):
  '''Returns a function that maps each index in 0, 1, ..., n-1 to a distinct 
  RGB color; the keyword argument name must be a standard mpl colormap name.'''
  return plt.cm.get_cmap(name, n)

if len(sys.argv)!=3:
  print("Syntax: {0} <Shapefile> <Output>".format(sys.argv[0]))
  sys.exit(-1)

shapefile_name = sys.argv[1]
outputfile     = sys.argv[2]

polys  = shapefile.Reader(shapefile_name)
shapes = polys.shapes()
cmap   = get_cmap(len(shapes))

#Enable to randomize colours
#random.shuffle(shapes)

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_axes((0,0,1,1)) 

for i,poly in enumerate(shapes):
  poly  = poly.__geo_interface__
  color = cmap(i)
  ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(poly, fc=None, ec="black", alpha=1, zorder=2))

ax.axis('scaled')
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.savefig(outputfile, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead, just load the shp file into ArcMaps and configure it how you like.  Then use either Alt + Print Screen or the Snipping Tool to get a screenshot.  Then you will have a jpg or png that looks exactly like how the shape file was rendered.

Comment: I don't think that addresses the key component of the question which is how to **automate** the process.